# Flutter Supabase - Create Table

Tags: flutter

How can I create a table in flutter SUPABASE instead of first creating it from SUPABASE SQL editor and then access it through our flutter project also how to add a row in that table?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.